# How to terminate and iterate on nested ngFor in angular2

Tags: html, angular, ngfor

I need to show below UI template list using nested ngFor:

> **17th March, 2017:**
>   **07:26 AM**   Item1,Item2,Item3
>   **07:15 AM**   Item6,Item5,Item4
>   **07:10 AM**   Item7,Item8,Item9
>
> **16th March, 2017:**
>   **08:26 AM**   Item10,Item20,Item30
>   **08:15 AM**   Item60,Item50,Item40
>   **06:10 AM**   Item70,Item80,Item90

The challenge I've is I get a single JSON as below:

```
[{
"date":"17th March, 2017",
"time":"07:26 AM",
"items":"item1,item2,item3"
},{
"date":"17th March, 2017",
"time":"07:15 AM",
"items":"item6,item5,item4"
},{
"date":"17th March, 2017",
"time":"07:10 AM",
"items":"item7,item8,item9"
},{
"date":"16th March, 2017",
"time":"08:26 AM",
"items":"item10,item20,item30"
},{
"date":"16th March, 2017",
"time":"08:15 AM",
"items":"item60,item50,item40"
},{
"date":"16th March, 2017",
"time":"06:10 AM",
"items":"item70,item80,item90"
}
]
```

So can someone help/suggest me on how to form a nested template to show above list and to terminate the inner ngFor when date changes as per data.

Comment: Where is the nested part at ? There is only one array.

Comment: @YounesM first loop is on date and the second one is on time as per JSON, do let me know if you need any more information.

Comment: Please post the code that demonstrates what you tried and where you failed.

Comment: Can i add an answer in angular 1 and you transform it ??

Comment: @ModarNa  yes I am good with angular1 as well, so please go ahead with it.I will transform to angular2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using two `Pipe`'s, it could look like this:

Maybe `StringToArrayPipe` isn't needed, if you only want to show that string..

```js
@Pipe({ name: 'stringToArray' })
export class StringToArrayPipe implements PipeTransform {
  public transform(value: string): string[] {
    if (!value) return [];
    return value.split(',');
  }
}

@Pipe({ name: 'mergeDuplicates' })
export class MergeDuplicatesPipe implements PipeTransform {
  public transform(values: any[]): any[] {
    if (!values || !values.length) return [];
    return values.reduce((prev, cur) => {
      const tmp = prev.find(v => v.date == cur.date);
      if (!tmp) {
        prev.push({
          date: cur.date,
          timeAndItems: [
            { time: cur.time, items: cur.items }
          ]
        });
      }
      else {
        tmp.timeAndItems.push({
          time: cur.time,
          items: cur.items
        });
      }
      return prev;
    }, []);
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>

      <div *ngFor="let d of (_data | mergeDuplicates)">
         <b>{{ d.date }}</b>
         <ul>
          <li *ngFor="let timeAndItems of d.timeAndItems">
            <b>{{ timeAndItems.time }}</b>
            <span style="margin-left: 5px;" *ngFor="let i of (timeAndItems.items | stringToArray)">{{ i }}</span>
          </li>
         </ul>
      </div>

    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name:string;

  private _data = [
    {
      "date":"17th March, 2017",
      "time":"07:26 AM",
      "items":"item1,item2,item3"
    },{
      "date":"17th March, 2017",
      "time":"07:15 AM",
      "items":"item6,item5,item4"
    },{
      "date":"17th March, 2017",
      "time":"07:10 AM",
      "items":"item7,item8,item9"
    },{
      "date":"16th March, 2017",
      "time":"08:26 AM",
      "items":"item10,item20,item30"
    },{
      "date":"16th March, 2017",
      "time":"08:15 AM",
      "items":"item60,item50,item40"
    },{
      "date":"16th March, 2017",
      "time":"06:10 AM",
      "items":"item70,item80,item90"
    }
  ];

  constructor() {
    this.name = 'Angular2'
  }
}
```

live-demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/W1dJzqiSqhy83rmY4Xyc?p=preview

Comment: The outer loop should get unique values or else will produce duplicates .. see the OP format Above

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
<div ng-repeat="outer in list | unique:'date' >
    <h1>{{outer.date}}</h1>
    <div ng-repeat="inner in list" ng-if="inner.date===outer.date">
        <h4>{{inner.time}}</h4> : {{inner.items}}</h4>
    </div>
</div>
```

Outer loop gets unique dates

Inner loop displays time and items when `inner.date = outer.date`

Morever .. if `items` is a list then you need a third loop same logic as above

Comment: Thank you, I think this looks good for me as per the code above. I will try out the same logic with angular2.